# POPUP окно с периодом времени

Tags: html, css, javascript

Приветствую,помогите пожалуйста реализовать функцию POP-UP окна.Меня интересует как сделать так что бы окно высвечивалось с периодом времени.К примеру : Вы зашли на сайт,вам всплыло : "Привет",и так каждый день.JScript плохо знаю,не web кодер.Надеюсь найдется человек который поможет!Спасибо заранее)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При заходе на сайт проверяйте наличие Вашей куки:

1) Вашей куки нет:

- покзываете popup
- ставьте куку с экспайром в 24 часа

2) Ваша кука есть:

- ничего не делаете